# Differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know this is a stupid question, but it has been a long time since I did analysis. Could somebody show me how to show rigorously that $f(x)= |x|_\mathrm{eucl}^2$ is differentiable for all $x\in R^n$? I remember that the definition of differentiability involves if there exists a linear map $L$ s.t. ${|f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)-L(\epsilon)|\over|\epsilon|}\to0$ as $|\epsilon|\to0$ But is it necessary to find $L$ beforehand or is there some other way?

Sorry about this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can invoke theorems: here, the partial derivatives of $f$ are all continuous, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = 2x_i$, so the function is differentiable.

Comment: You do not have to use the definition. In your case it suffices to show that $f$ is continuously differentiable with respect to every coordinate.
Try to write $f$ using such coordinates $x_1,\dots,x_n$.
Calculating the partial derivatives should be easy after that.

Comment: Thanks, Arturo and Matthias!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going directly to the definition is unnecessarily complicated. The sane way to prove this is in steps:

- Every constant function and each of the coordinate functions is differentiable (because it *is* a linear map).
- Products and sums of differentiable functions are differentiable (with the usual product and sum rules; the definition can be used here, or you can reduce it to partial derivatives and use the equivalent result from single-variable analysis).
- Every polynomial in the coordinate functions is differentiable (by the two previous points; no direct use of the definition).
- Your $f(x)=|x|^2= x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2$ is a polynomial in the coordinates and is therefore differentiable.

Comment: THanks, this is MUCH better!